# Is there a way to get Google Sheets to default to a different tab each day?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-apps-script, razor, google-sheets

I have an MVC application that links to a Google Sheet doc via siteloader. It's loading great but defaulting to load the first tab in the sheets - working as designed obviously.

Here's what I need to do:

The tabs in this sheet are separated by date. So, for example, today's 8/22/20. The tab displays "SAT 082220." Tomorrow's tab will be "SUN 082320" and so on.

I need siteloader to default to today's tab when the project loads. So basically it just needs to load the next tab in the list each day.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

I know Google Sheets assigns its own unique URL to each tab in the sheet via the edit#gid= in the URL.

Is there a pattern to the tab URL so I could have siteloader constantly just load the next tab in the list each day? i.e. edit#gid=1068387962 for today's tab and edit#gid=somethingsomething for tomorrow's?

I'm thinking that may be the easiest way. From what I can see, though, it all looks random.

Alternatively, is there a way to get razor to read the tabs and match the tab name with `DateTime.now`?

Comment: Apparently each tab has its own URL.  So just use the correct URL based on the date.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I won't know what the URL is for each date - it seems there's no pattern so I don't know which URL to point to for each date without manually entering the URL each day - which isn't an option. Any idea how to get the app to figure it out?

Comment: I take it you're creating new tabs from scratch each week.

Comment: Correct. The person who maintains it manually adds a new tab for each day about a week at a time.

Comment: And he knows what that URL is for each day he adds.

Comment: Yeah. I will too but we'd have to go into the code each day (or set up a variable GUI) to manually change  - which we just don't have time for. It would be amazing to automate that somehow.

Comment: Make an input form that accepts that URL in a text box.

Comment: If you have time to manually put the spreadsheets in, you have time to put the URL in so your program can get to it.

Comment: That's an option that would work I guess.... I'm really, really hoping to get that automated somehow. But that could work.

Comment: I had a quick look at those Sheet URLs.  While there does seem to be a pattern (it appears to be an incrementing ID), I don't think there's any way to predict what the next one is going to be.  The prefix of `gid=` suggests that it increments globally for every user putting in a new spreadsheet or tab.  I could be wrong though; I don't work for Google.

Comment: I think you're 100 percent right.... which makes my job a lot harder. I think your suggestion to enter the URL, while cumbersome, may actually be the best option. Have a database set up so she can document each URL for each day in advance... I'm not excited by the idea but I think that may be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onOpen`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger on apps script can do this:

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnOpen} e
 */
const onOpen = e =>
  e.source
    .getSheetByName(
      Utilities.formatDate(
        new Date(),
        e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
        'EEE MMddyy'
      ).toUpperCase()
    )
    .activate();
```